# Opening a sub-page in react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

In my react app I have this App.js file

```js
import React from 'react';
import Login from './pages/Login';

function App() {
  return (
    <Login />
  );
}
export default App;
```

My Login.Js has this link in it (and some stuff that is irrelevant to the question)

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import '../css/App.css';
import '../css/Login.css'
import 'w3-css';
import logo from '../images/logo.png';

class Login extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
               <p style={{fontSize:'14px'}}>Admin? <a href="admin">Login as admin</a></p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

So when the user clicks the link it opens a sub-page with the domain `localhost:3000/admin`
How would I update my UI accordingly and open a new file similar to Login.js where I can construct the next view

Comment: take a look at https://reactrouter.com/ (here a minimal example https://reactrouter.com/web/example/basic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up the front-end routing of your project using `react-router-dom` package.

Like below,

```
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import AdminPage from 'path/to/your/AdminPage'
import Login from 'path/to/your/Login'

const RoutedApp = () => {

    return (
       <Switch>
         <Route exact path="/admin" component={AdminPage}/>
         <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}/>
       </Switch>
    );
}

export default RoutedApp;
```

then set `RoutedApp` as the starting point of your app (In the `index.js`  file)

```
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <RoutedApp />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: @Adventure, let me know any issues while setting it up

Comment: When opening in browser this results in totally white page!

Comment: Okay you updated the answer and it renders the login page but not the admin page

Comment: Just visit http://localhost:3000/admin to check whether admin page is working or not

Comment: No it does not! I visited it and it displayed the login view

Comment: How does your `AdminPage` look like? Maybe you have duplicated content same as the login page.

Comment: Your root page(localhost:3000/) should look empty. You also need to add a new route`<Route exact path="/" component={HomePage}/>` and a component like `HomePage`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/czTg6cDq here is my Admin.js Login.js App.js and index.js i have no idea what is wrong. Is it that the login page is on `localhost:3000/`

Comment: Okay I found my problem I wasn't using the `exact` keyword in my routes